# How do I visit all edges incident to a vertex in a DCEL data structure?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, computational-geometry, doubly-connected-edge-list

In a doubly-connected edge list (DCEL) data structure, each vertex `v` stores a pointer to one arbitrary half-edge, `v.inc`, which has `v` as its origin, that is, `v.inc.origin == v`. However, there may be multiple half-edges which have `v` as its origin.

How do I access or iterate all half-edges which have `v` has their origin?

Answer (score 2):

We can do that by exploiting the structure of the DCEL.

Recall first that each half-edge `h` has a pointer to its twin half-edge, `h.twin`. Each half-edge `h` also has a pointer to its successor, `h.next`, and predecessor, `h.prev`, half-edges, which lie on the boundary of its incident face (that is, on the boundary of `h.face`), assuming that the incident face of `h` lies to its left (if we walk, in a counter-clockwise matter, along the edges incident to `h.face` by following the "next" pointers).

So, how do we visit all half-edges which have a vertex `v` as their origin?

The solution consists in exploiting the pointers `h.twin` and `h.next`.

Let `h` be the half-edge such that a vertex `v` stores `h` as its own incident half-edge (that is, `h == v.inc`), where `v` is the vertex that we want to know all half-edges which have `v` as its origin, where `h` is one of those half-edges. We can then access `h.twin`, which has `v` as its destination. Hence, `h.twin.next` is a half-edge which also leaves `v`. Unless  `v` is adjacent only to one vertex `u`, which implies that `v.inc == h` is the only half-edge leaving `v` (and we are done), then `h.twin.next` is different from `h`. In that case, let `w = h.twin.next`. Then `w.twin` is a half-edge which has `v` as its destination (i.e. like `h.twin`). Hence, `w.twin.next` is also a half-edge which leaves `v`. We can proceed in this matter until `w.twin.next` is equal to `h`.

In a more formal way, the algorithm may look as follows.

```
function all_half_edges_leaving(v):
    h = v.inc
    list = [h]
    w = h.twin.next
    while w != h:
        list.append(w)
        w = w.twin.next
   return list
```

Clearly, once we have the half-edges leaving `v`, we can access in constant time also its twins (given that each half-edge stores a pointer to its twin). Alternatively, we may also store the twins in a list during the procedure above.